# Object Does not support this property or method in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a code that will collate data from multiple workbooks in a folder in to one single sheet.
Now, I am trying to make the code read through all the worksheets in the workbooks with the below code. I get the error - "Object Doesnt support this property or method" in the highlighted line.

```
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files

RowCount = ws1.UsedRange.Rows.Count

If objFile.Type = "Microsoft Excel Worksheet" Or objFile.Type = "Microsoft Excel Macro-Enabled Worksheet" Then

Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(path & objFile.Name)

For Each ws_cnt In wb '<---Error here.

Set srWS = wb.Sheets(1)
```

Comment: What are you trying to iterate over?  `wb` is a Workbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`For Each ws_cnt In wb.Worksheets`

You need to specify the collection that you wish to iterate over, so in this instance it is the `wb.Worksheets` collection.

Then you can just work with the worksheet.

`ws_cnt.Range("A1").Copy`